Spring MVC - Why do I need a model object in a GET request?
Take a look at the example Spring provides for handling form submissions:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-handling-form-submission/tree/main/complete
It's a basic example of a Spring MVC controller that handles forms. Let's look at the controller class:
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "result";
    }

}

So first the user browses to GET /greeting, which returns a HTML form, which is then submitted to POST /greeting.
My question is, why do we add a Greeting object to the model in the @GetMapping method? The form is an empty form, it doesn't do anything with this model object?

In the documentation to their Github repo it explains this:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content
"The value of the name parameter is added to a Model object, ultimately making it accessible to the view template."
